# System freezes sometimes after resuming from suspend

Tags: linux-mint, kde, suspend, freeze

I've been having this problem for quite some time. Sometimes (I guess about one in five times) my laptop completely freezes after I try to resume from suspend. The screen displays the screensaver or password prompt, completely frozen; keyboard and mouse don't work at all, not even Caps lock or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>.

I've been trying to solve this for weeks, with no success so far. This is what I tried (based on answers to similar issues I found on the internet), rebooting after each of them:

1. Uncomment `SAVE_VIDEO_PCI_STATE=true` in the file */etc/default/acpi-support*.
2. Add `resume=UUID=<swap-partition-uuid>` to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the file */etc/default/grub* and run `update-grub`.
3. Check that the aforementioned swap partition UUID is correct in */etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume* and */etc/fstab*.
4. Update the kernel to the latest version.
5. Reinstall the package *xserver-xorg-input-all*.
6. Add `atkbd.reset i8042.nomux` to the variable mentioned in item 2 and run `update-grub`.

What else can I do in order to solve this problem? Thank you.

---

Some info about my system (I can add more if needed, just ask):

```
$ uname -a
Linux ViniciusInspiron 4.9.2-040902-generic #201701090331 SMP Mon Jan 9 08:33:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/linuxmint/info
RELEASE=17.3
CODENAME=rosa
EDITION="KDE 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa"
DESKTOP=KDE
TOOLKIT=QT
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rosa_kde_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rosa_kde.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=`yelp help:linuxmint`
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 17.3 KDE 64-bit
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:43 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 69
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 1678.857
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4788.57
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 69
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 1700.097
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4789.50
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 69
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 1337.109
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4790.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 69
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 1619.531
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4789.62
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```